# Multidimensional tensor product in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, multiplication, tensor

In pytorch I have to tensors of dimensions [K,L,M] and [M,L,N]. I want to perform a standard tensor convolution product of those tensors along the middle two dimensions to obtain a [K,N] tensor. I couldn't find official documentation on how to perform those operations, perhaps it should be better done in some other library and then reconverted to pytorch tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by convolution you actually mean something like contraction, you're probably looking for [`torch.tensordot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.tensordot.html). You can specify the indices that should be contracted.